# Cut image off to the left inside of a section, and prevent it from moving as the window scales

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, responsive-images

I have homepage hero I am trying to create and I want to have an image cut off on the left. The issue I am running into, is how to handle the image scaling down and getting cut off farther and farther to the left? Is there no way around this, but to create a bunch of media queries?

Would it be better perhaps to move the image in-line HTML, as opposed to having it live as a background in a div? (I have tried this method, also to no avail.)

```css
.hero {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 640px;
  max-width: -webkit-fill-available;
}

.hero-image {
  width: 979px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(http://www.pngmart.com/files/1/Audi-Car-Front-View-PNG.png);
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 65%;
  top: -39%;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="hero-image"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-push-5">
        <h1>Hero Header Here</h1>
        <p>Hero text here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ncsztfmg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `right:65%`, give it `left:-700px` (`-700px` or any convenient as per to your image).

> Not a Percentage value, as it will force your image to reposition.

```css
.hero {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 640px;
  max-width: -webkit-fill-available;
}

.hero-image {
  width: 979px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(http://www.pngmart.com/files/1/Audi-Car-Front-View-PNG.png);
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: -700px;
  top: -39%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="hero-image"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h1>Hero Header Here</h1>
        <p>Hero text here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set image as background for main section and position it with
**background-position-x**

Here is css

```
.hero {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x:  hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 640px;
  max-width: -webkit-fill-available;
  background-image: url(http://www.pngmart.com/files/1/Audi-Car-Front-View-PNG.png);
  background-position-x:-600px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ncsztfmg/1/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Sergey Orlov! I will try out this method too!